# warning: ignoring file ../lib/mobileRTC.framework/mobileRTC, missing required architecture x86_64 in file ../lib/mobileRTC.framework/mobileRTC

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, zoom-sdk

I am trying to run the sample project of zoom api.

https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-ios

I double checked all the instructions and looked for everywhere about "Apple mach-O linker error." All the results were about linking the frameworks. I have all the frameworks included in Link Binary With Libraries. Then above all the errors I noticed this warning which says about ignoring the framework because of missing architecture. Here is the list of warning and errors.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../lib/mobileRTC.framework/mobileRTC, missing required architecture x86_64 in file ../lib/mobileRTC.framework/mobileRTC (2 slices)
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_kMeetingParam_UserID", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
      "_kMeetingParam_IsAppShare", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
      "_kMeetingParam_MeetingNumber", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
          -[MainViewController joinMeeting:withPassword:] in MainViewController.o
      "_kMeetingParam_MeetingPassword", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController joinMeeting:withPassword:] in MainViewController.o
      "_kMeetingParam_Username", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
          -[MainViewController joinMeeting:withPassword:] in MainViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MobileRTC", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in InviteViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
          objc-class-ref in LanguaguePickerViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in ScheduleTableViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MeetingSettingsViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
          ...
      "_kMeetingParam_UserType", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
      "_kMeetingParam_UserToken", referenced from:
          -[MainViewController startMeeting:] in MainViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MobileRTCInviteHelper", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in InviteViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this warning? I feel like if I can somehow make it not to ignore that framework, the errors will be gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like MobileRTC.framework really doesn't contain an x86 binary inside. If you try to launch the project on real device you'll succeed.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I also read about this but I am working on a remote os x device and I have no other option but to use a simulator.

Comment: then you probably need to address this question to framework vendor why they didn't build the library for x86_64 architecture, this is strange

Comment: another crazy idea is to use the software for connecting usb devices to remote computer. I tried this approach once, it's working)

Comment: I will. Thanks. If I have a chance to try it on a real device and it works, I will give your credit.